# C - Reverse Converter Process

Tags: c, binary, byte

**Context:**

I'm trying to reverse the process of a `c` converter. This is the **original converter**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("input.bin", "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int s = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);

    FILE *o = fopen("output.txt", "wb");

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < s / 4; i++) {
        unsigned int u;
        fread(&u, sizeof(u), 1, f);
        fprintf(o, "u32[%d] = 0x%08x;\n", i, u);
    }

    fclose(o);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

What it does is it creates a new file called `output.txt` and converts the `.bin` file to bytes in a order like this:

```
u32[0] = 0x53555441;
u32[1] = 0x6373b848;
u32[2] = 0x74654e65;
u32[3] = 0x83486f53;
u32[4] = 0x0ebe60ec;
u32[5] = 0x48000000;
u32[6] = 0x40245c8d;
u32[7] = 0x24448948;
u32[8] = 0xda894840;
u32[9] = 0x244c8d48;
u32[10] = 0x024fbf10;
u32[11] = 0xc0310000;
u32[12] = 0x482444c7;
u32[13] = 0x74656b63;
```

**Question:**

Now, what I'm trying to do is the opposite. So, I'm trying to convert the output bytes of the above converter to a `.bin` file again, like its original state.

I tried this, but I'm stuck on the loop part:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("loader.txt", "rb"); // INPUT
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int s = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);

    FILE *o = fopen("loader.bin", "wb"); // OUTPUT

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < s / 4; i++) {
        // grab u32 bytes from loader.txt and convert into a .bin
    }

    fclose(o);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Would be amazingly appriciated.

---

Edit

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("loader.txt", "rb"); // INPUT
    rewind(f);

    FILE *o = fopen("loader.bin", "wb"); // OUTPUT

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < s / 4; i++) {
        fgets(f);
    sscanf(f);
    }

    fclose(o);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I saw a similar question to this earlier that had a solution, but I can't find it now...

Comment: @ChrisTurner True, it's because I deleted it because it got flagged for not explaining it too well, couldn't post the question afterwards because of the downvotes the account got locked.

Comment: please name your variables with meaningful names, single letter variables aren't helping anyone

Comment: The `fseek()`/`ftell()` operations aren't helpful.  You need to read each line from the text file with `fgets()`, then scan it with `sscanf()` to get the offset and value, then you need to seek to the relevant offset and write the value.  You are playing with text, not binary, data in the reverse code.  Just for giggles, note that it won't matter whether the data in the text file is in sequence or not; your program should work fine with missing or out of order (or repeated) offsets.  If you want to, you can enforce that the input is in the correct, non-repetitive, gapless order.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you mind making a small example so I can understand you better? I've been trying to get it working but sadly did not turn out successful.

Comment: Show what you tried based on the comments I gave, and explain where your code is going wrong.  You can update the question with the extra code because there isn't yet an answer.  It's basically a straight-forward application of the guidelines I gave.  You need to think through them and at least show where you have issues.  You can ignore my "just for giggles" comments — just go for the simple-minded approach: read a line, find the offset from inside the `u32[13]` part of the input, and the value from the `0x12345678` part.  It's probably sensible to ignore blank lines (but that isn't crucial).

Comment: If someone else answers before you update your question with your revised attempt, _add_ your revised effort.  If no-one has answered, you can _replace_ your current effort with your revised effort.  Add a comment `@JonathanLeffler` when there's an update.  I probably won't come back otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've updated the question with what I have, it's not much because I'm kinda really stuck on what to do. I know that I need to scan each line, but how can I convert the bytes into a bin again? Are there any particular functions for that?

Comment: You're right; that's not a serious attempt.  Use the manual pages for [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) and
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) (bookmark the POSIX index page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) and have a serious go.  Start with reading and printing the lines uninterpreted — using `fgets()` and `fputs()` (or `printf()`).  Then think about what I said — you'll find [`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html) useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmmm; ignore my comment about `strchr()` — I was confused about which question I was looking at.  You don't need it; plain `sscanf()` will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code which seems to do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char i_file[] = "loader.txt";
    const char o_file[] = "loader.bin";
    FILE *f = fopen(i_file, "rb"); // INPUT
    if (f == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", i_file);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *o = fopen(o_file, "wb"); // OUTPUT
    if (o == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for writing\n", o_file);
        return 1;
    }

    char line[1024];
    int lineno = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != 0)
    {
        int u32num;
        unsigned int value;
        lineno++;
        if (line[0] == '\n')
            continue;   // Blank lines ignored
        if (sscanf(line, "u32[%d] = %x", &u32num, &value) == 2)
        {
            fseek(o, u32num * sizeof(value), SEEK_SET);
            if (fwrite(&value, sizeof(value), 1, o) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write 0x%.8X to offset %d in %s\n",
                        value, u32num, o_file);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Input line %d in %s is mal-formatted: %s", lineno, i_file, line);
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(o);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

When run on the sample data from the question (`loader.txt`):

```
u32[0] = 0x53555441;
u32[1] = 0x6373b848;
u32[2] = 0x74654e65;
u32[3] = 0x83486f53;
u32[4] = 0x0ebe60ec;
u32[5] = 0x48000000;
u32[6] = 0x40245c8d;
u32[7] = 0x24448948;
u32[8] = 0xda894840;
u32[9] = 0x244c8d48;
u32[10] = 0x024fbf10;
u32[11] = 0xc0310000;
u32[12] = 0x482444c7;
u32[13] = 0x74656b63;
```

the output file (`loader.bin`) is:

```
$ odx loader.bin
0x0000: 41 54 55 53 48 B8 73 63 65 4E 65 74 53 6F 48 83   ATUSH.sceNetSoH.
0x0010: EC 60 BE 0E 00 00 00 48 8D 5C 24 40 48 89 44 24   .`.....H.\$@H.D$
0x0020: 40 48 89 DA 48 8D 4C 24 10 BF 4F 02 00 00 31 C0   @H..H.L$..O...1.
0x0030: C7 44 24 48 63 6B 65 74                           .D$Hcket
0x0038:
$
```

where `odx` is simply a home-grown hex dump program (you could use `od` or `xxd` or other programs to achieve similar results).  Taking the original conversion code verbatim (it compiled cleanly under my stringent compilation options — well done), and copying `loader.bin` to `input.bin`, the output is:

```
u32[0] = 0x53555441;
u32[1] = 0x6373b848;
u32[2] = 0x74654e65;
u32[3] = 0x83486f53;
u32[4] = 0x0ebe60ec;
u32[5] = 0x48000000;
u32[6] = 0x40245c8d;
u32[7] = 0x24448948;
u32[8] = 0xda894840;
u32[9] = 0x244c8d48;
u32[10] = 0x024fbf10;
u32[11] = 0xc0310000;
u32[12] = 0x482444c7;
u32[13] = 0x74656b63;
```

This is the same as the original input file, so the pair of programs can round-trip their data (run the two programs in turn and get as final output the data stored as the original input).  Note that the code has not been tested on a binary file with a length that is not a multiple of 4 bytes; there are issues to worry about there.

Comment: Simply amazing. Thanks a LOT!